# GIT Detached head issue on a branch

Tags: git, git-detached-head

I created a branch for my change and did a lots of commit over there.
But then I wanted to rollback my latest commit. sO i did following
1. I checkout the previous commit with
git checkout  on my branch.
2. Then I did my changes to local directory and committed the changes.

Now I am not able to push it to the branch head.
It is showing as detached head and can't see this commit in GIT UI.

Please note I want to push the changes to the head of my branch and not to the master.
Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
# create a branch where you're currently pointing at
git branch temp

git checkout your_branch
git merge temp
```

and the commit you made out of your branch will be brought in, it should be a fast-forward (so *without* an unnecessary merge commit).

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I already have checkout my branch. And then I checkout the previous commit and then I made changes and committed it back. I just need to push it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you checked out your previous commit without resetting your branch to it, therefore detaching `HEAD`. To bring back the branch to your current `HEAD` (and drop the commit it was pointing to), just use:

```
git checkout -B your_branch # Reset your_branch to HEAD and attach to it
```

If you had already pushed the dropped commit, you will need to `--force` the next push.